# how to open port 3017 in debian 6.0

Tags: linux, debian

what is the command to open the port 3017 in debian 6.0 ? pretty straightforward question I found different commands to type I dont want to type stuff I am unsure about so I am asking on here. (I trust the valuable stackoverflow members)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3017 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: restarting iptables will probably wipe the rule